# May one read a map or document hung on the wall by a Jew during Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, sin, hanaah-benefit

Let's say a Jew hung a map or a document on the wall on Shabbos.

For the purposes of this question, let's assume that this was a desecration of Shabbos (presumably because of the prohibition on completing the construction of something on Shabbos).

Would another Jew be permitted to look at this map or document after Shabbos?

Or would this qualify as impermissibly benefiting from an act of Shabbos desecration?

Comment: Actually, reading any map on a wall may transgress the issur of Shtarot Hedyotot. See Kitzur סימן צ - דין עשית חפציו בלא מלאכה ומלאכה על ידי גוי : סעיף י' 

שִׁטְרֵי הֶדְיוֹטוֹת, דְּהַיְנוּ שִׁטְרֵי חוֹבוֹת וְחֶשְׁבּוֹנוֹת וְאִגְּרוֹת שֶׁל שְׁאֵלַת שָׁלוֹם, אָסוּר אֲפִלּוּ לְעַיֵּן בָּהֶם בְּלִי קְרִיאָה (בפיו), וְאַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵינוֹ אֶלָּא מְהַרְהֵר, מִכָּל מָקוֹם אָסוּר סעיף יא' 

כֹּתֶל אוֹ טַבְלָא שֶׁיֵּשׁ בּוֹ אֵיזֶה צוּרוֹת אוֹ דְּיוֹקְנָאוֹת (פאטרעטן) וְכָתוּב תַּחְתֵּיהֶן, זוֹ צוּרַת פְּלוֹנִי וְזֶה דְיוֹקָן פְּלוֹנִי, אָסוּר לִקְרוֹת כְּתָב זֶה בְּשַׁבָּת.

Answer (score 1):

After Shabbat another Jew can benefit from this map/document. However, if it was an intentional desecration, the violator is never allowed to benefit from it.

There are also those who pasken that *b'shogeg* (accidentally), all can benefit even that very Shabbat, and *b'meizid* (intentionally), even the violator himself can benefit after Shabbat. However, this is only if it is very important.

See http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/ostroff/archives/shabbosVI-34.pdf

This is of course, assuming that this is a melacha.

Comment: Is reading it in its new position even benefiting at all?

Comment: Well, if it was previously inaccessible, it might be, but it might not be if it was, say, sitting on the table.